# Can I make nodejs addon replacing "exports" object?

Tags: node.js

```
function myfunc() {
    // some codes...
}

exports = myfunc;
```

When nodejs addon is above type, I can use it as ...

```
var myfunc = require("./myfunc");
myfunc();
```

How can I make this type addon in c++?

Answer (score 2):

You can set `myfunc` as the `exports` object by setting [`module.exports`](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports) directly:

```
function myfunc() {
}

module.exports = myfunc;
```

The [Modules](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules) documentation covers the distinction between `exports` and `module.exports`:

> Note that `exports` is a reference to `module.exports` making it suitable
>   for augmentation only. If you are exporting a single item such as a
>   constructor you will want to use `module.exports` directly instead.
>
> ```
> function MyConstructor (opts) {
>   //...
> }
>
> // BROKEN: Does not modify exports
> exports = MyConstructor;
>
> // exports the constructor properly
> module.exports = MyConstructor;
> ```

---

As for making it a [C++ Addon](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html), a rough example would be:

```
#include <node.h>

using namespace v8;

Handle<Value> MyFunc(const Arguments& args) {
  HandleScope scope;
  return scope.Close(Undefined());
}

void Init(Handle<Object> exports, Handle<Object> module) {
    module->Set(
        String::NewSymbol("exports"),
        FunctionTemplate::New(MyFunc)->GetFunction()
    );
}

NODE_MODULE(target_name, Init);
```

To build it, you'll need [`node-gyp`](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp), [its dependencies](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp#installation), and a [`binding.gyp`](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp#the-bindinggyp-file).

And, note that the 1st argument for `NODE_MODULE()` should match the value of `"target_name"` in the `binding.gyp`.

Then:

```
node-gyp rebuild
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 1 more question. node's init() function accepts only exports argument. How can I get module handle from Init() function?

Comment: @chaeyk To access `module`, define `Init` to take a 2nd `Handle<Object>`. The snippet above demonstrates this. And, to be clear, `Init` is a function within the addon's source code, not within Node's. It can be given any name. Node just needs to be instructed to call it by passing it to `NODE_MODULE()`.

Comment: yeah.. NODE_MODULE() macro sets modname and register function to node_module_struct struct, and register_func is defined like that..
struct node_module_struct {
  int version;
  void *dso_handle;
  const char *filename;
  void (*register_func) (v8::Handle<v8::Object> target);
  const char *modname;
};
so, cannot accept Init(exports, module)